# How to debug this bug when reversing an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code in python 3 trying to reverse an array. The code gives output and shows a run time exception.

```
for N in range(int(input())):
    arr = str(input())
    print(''.join(map(str, reversed(arr))))
```

Exception I am facing:

```
 File "solution.py", line 2, in <module>
    arr = str(input())
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. In what environment do you execute it?

Comment: *the correct way to debug this bug* Perhaps you are looking for a "debugger"?  ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove EOFError: EOF when reading a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891603/how-to-remove-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)

Comment: Are you redirecting the input of your Python script?

Comment: @0x5453 How would a "debugger" tell you why a built-in function like `input()` is reporting an error?

Comment: We would need to see the input file. The most likely cause is that the line count, N, is wrong. You are hitting EOF on the file, which means you are trying to read a line that doesn't exist.

Comment: i am running this code on Hackerrank. There is no input file just this lines i have written on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably point to the hackerrank problem you are trying to solve. I assume it is this one:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-arrays/problem

The problem only has two lines. The first line is the number of elements on the one-dimensional array. The second line contains N space-separated integers. You should only have two input() calls, and you are trying to do N+1, so the third call fails.

Note also that you cannot just reverse the line. If the array line has 15 16 then '61 51' is not the correct answer, it should be '16 15'.