# EOFError: EOF when reading a line on raw_input in Python

Tags: python

So I got a couple threads running in Python and I am trying to get a value in each, I want the user to be able to input an entry in order to start the thread once the value has been returned for example:

```
def adding(self):
   print 'Hello'
   name = raw_input("Press enter once hello is printed... ")
   execute rest of function .........
```

However when I do this, I get error :

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 495, in run
    self.adding()
  File "/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 285, in adding
    name = raw_input("Press enter once hello is printed... ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

What am I doing wrong or how can i change this in order to do what i want to do.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891603/how-to-remove-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? If you're calling `raw_input` on multiple threads, the fact that most of them get an `EOFError` at quit time would be expected. If it's happening earlier than that (and you aren't reading from a redirected file or pipe, and the user isn't hitting Ctrl-D, etc.), it's clearly a different problem, but hard to guess what that problem is, or debug it, without a [mcve].