# EOFError, even after trying the try and except block

Tags: python-3.x, eoferror

Could anyone please state the reason why it is showing. I acknowledge it as python after reading the input states that there is nothing to read.

> Python 3.6

```
    #!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

while True:
    try:
        N = int(input())
    except EOFError:
        return
#N = int(input())


if N % 2 != 0:
    print("Wierd")
elif N % 2 == 0 and N in range(2, 6):
    print("Not Wierd")
elif N % 2 == 0 and N in range(6, 21):
    print("Wierd")
elif N % 2 == 0 and N > 20:
    print("Wierd")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
```

the error statement

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 27, in <module>
    N = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Blockquote
```

Comment: How are you testing this? What were you entering in the terminal prompt as int inputs and then to stop the `input()` (ex. Ctrl+C?)? I can't reproduce because if I use Ctrl+C to stop the `input()` I get the `KeyboardInterrupt` error, not the `EOFError`.

Comment: The `return` line looks strange... Where's the function?

Comment: Hi @GinoMempin,
Testing is done itself in the code given by the website editor as stub code. Regarding this, the input is stdin and in the same way stdout. [https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-conditional-statements/problem] . Thanks

Comment: @iBug, I too had the same intriguing question before trying the return. But a fellow [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42891677/10255905] had answered to similar question to use return to make it return nothing when EOF exception error comes.

Comment: @GinoMempin, the link that i have share for the website will not navigate you to the place where i am practicing the code, it needs to be unlocked with the previous challenges. But everything in the editor i have pasted here in the post.

Comment: Hmm I think something is still missing.. a function perhaps? Because the code above `'__main__':` does not make sense with the `N = int(input())` inside it. You can try running [this repl](https://repl.it/@ginomempin/ActiveGraveOpensource) where I put everything inside main to get the correct behavior.

Comment: +1 @GinoMempin, Well mate!! it did worked. initially i thought not to mess with the stub code as they have to test the code i have coded inside. but it turns out that it was indeed a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` only works when you are inside a function and you want to exit from that function. In this case you just want to terminate your while loop so your should use `break` keyword.

Also in given question, you just need to read a single integer (I guess you are working on something different?)

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

while True:
    try:
        N = int(input())
    except EOFError:
        break
#N = int(input())


if N % 2 != 0:
    print("Wierd")
elif N % 2 == 0 and N in range(2, 6):
    print("Not Wierd")
elif N % 2 == 0 and N in range(6, 21):
    print("Wierd")
elif N % 2 == 0 and N > 20:
    print("Wierd")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
```