# python 3 EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python-3.x

The errors saying

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "rental_car-customer-data-2.py", line 18, in 
>     odoEnd = int(input("Ending Odometer Reading:"))
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line
> ```

I have tried removing int and copy paste same line from above that doesn't error odoStart and change it to odoEnd but not working??
not sure if the `odoEnd - odoStart` will work either?

```
odoStart = int(input ("Starting Odometer Reading:"))
odoEnd = int(input("Ending Odometer Reading:"))****
    print(odoStart)
    print(odoEnd)
totalMiles = (odoEnd - odoStart)  
    print (totalMiles)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove EOFError: EOF when reading a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891603/how-to-remove-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error when reading a file. When you get to the end of a file when reading in python you have to go back to line one by using this command: `file.seek(0)`, where `file` is the name of the file variable.