# Running two function together with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to 2 function to run together however first func1() should run and func1() should call func2() then both the function should run simultaneously till all the condition are met.
here is the dummy code

```
x=1
def func1():
    global x
    while x>0:
       a=input()
       do something
       if(true only once):
           func2()              #calling func2() only once


def func2():
    global x
    while 1:
       if x==5:
          x=0                   #x become 0 so now while loop for func1 should end
          break
      x+=1
```

Here first func1 will run and then func2, then both the function will run simultaneously till x value set as 0.
Here is my code that i try to run with multiprocessing.

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
from threading import *
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

bot_reply_time = 0
x = 1
def func1():
    y = 0
    global bot_reply_time
    while x > 0:
        a = input("Q>")                          #EOF error here when reading a line
        print("Bot replay: Hi")
        c = datetime.datetime.now()
        bot_reply_time = (c.hour * 60 * 60) + (c.minute * 60) + c.second
        if y == 0:
            y += 1
            p2 = Process(target=func2)          #calling func2 only once
            p2.start()
def func2():
    global x
    global bot_reply_time
    while True:
        last_bot_reply_time = bot_reply_time
        c = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_time = (c.hour * 60 * 60) + (c.minute * 60) + c.second
        if (bot_reply_time + 10 == current_time and bot_reply_time == last_bot_reply_time):
            x = 0                           #x become 0 so now while loop for func1 should end
            print("session expired")
            break


if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p1.start()
```

However i am getting error as "EOF when reading a line". I dont get error if i remove "input()"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove EOFError: EOF when reading a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891603/how-to-remove-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)

Comment: still not able to solve the problem...I was getting EOF error when I was using Thread and now I am using multiprocess, still I am getting EOF error

Comment: I added some code to make the concept more clear

Answer (score 1):

Using multiprocessing closes the input of all created processes because i wouldn't know which input belongs to which process. Also your global values will not be shared across multiple processes. What you acutally need is shared memory across the processes, which can be accomplished via [`multiprocessing.value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value).

To use that input function, you would have to put it in the main thread and share the input via shared memory with other functions that might need it.

And this would be to show the concept:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time

def func1(x):
    while x.value > 0:
        print(f"Bot replay: Hi with x {x.value}")
        time.sleep(1)
        p2 = Process(target=func2, args=(x.value,))   
        p2.start()

def func2(x):
    print(f"func2 printed x: {x}")

if __name__=='__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    x_value = manager.Value(int, 1)

    p1 = Process(target = func1, args=(x_value,))
    p1.start()

    while True:
        x_value.value = int(input("Q>"))
```