# Loop does not start with while

Tags: python

what did I do wrong?

I need to ask a question to the user inside the loop, but it doesn't run

Error:-

```
error: EOFError: EOF when reading a line "msg = input("test: ")"
```

Code:-

```
def while2():
    while True:
        msg = input("test: ")
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I just ran your example code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @COLDER It can be indentation - check tabs/spaces! Python is very picky  + make sure you don't forget conditions (in case of loops)  I accidentally thought you only had a while loop but then saw you have a definition and a '2' after it,

Comment: EOFError is common when input() function is interrupted in python. Just try and except the error when using input() function in python.

Comment: In addition, I believe `raw_input` is what you're looking for. `input` would try to evaluate the incoming string as code.

Comment: @COLDER do you have more code or is this just it?

Comment: @Northern That's only in Python 2, which is EOL. Fair point though, OP might be using it by accident.

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from Python? It might be coming from your IDE. For example apparently [VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65032738/4518341) can experience this error, and I wouldn't be surprised if IDLE could too. If you're sure, then please provide a [mre] including complete code (i.e. call to `while2()`) and any input.