# EOF error with raw_input - Issue executing Python script from a reverse shell

Tags: python-2.x, eof, raw-input, metasploit, reverse-shell

I am currently helping my university's cyber security program by creating a simple Capture the Flag style python script to be used for the final exam.  I created the script and everything is working great when run natively on Windows.  The issue that I am having is that since the course is dealing with ethical hacking, many of the students will be accessing the Windows machine via a reverse shell or meterpreter on their local Kali linux machine.  When I try to run the script through the meterpreter or reverse shell, I am having an EOF error as soon as my script asks for input, without waitingfor a user to type.

I tried to recreate a simple script in order to demonstrate the issue:

test.py:

```
    print "This is a test"
    answer = raw_input("Type anything")
    print answer
```

When I run the command through the meterpreter or reverse shell, the output is as follows

```
    > test.py
    This is a test
    Type anythingTraceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    answer = raw_input("Type anything")
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I have tried this with both `input` and `raw_input` and both have the same EOFError.  I've tried searching through similar posts, but none seem to address the issue.

My belief is that the reverse shell or meterpreter are causing the issue, but I can not find any information on how to remotely execute a python script on the target machine while using the meterpreter or reverse shell.

I appreciate any help or insight, as I am honestly quite stumped!

Comment: As an aside, you are using python 2.x which was end-of-life years ago. You'd do your cyber security program a favor by moving to the latest python.

Comment: @tdelaney - it needs to run on the host windows xp machine, so unfortunately 2.7 is the highest version available to me for that particular challenge.  I use 3.9 for all my other programming though.

Comment: @tdelaney I am pretty sure support for windows XP is ended in 2014 so the system should be upgraded or air gapped. As for the problem it looks like you are missing a loop see the bottom answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891603/how-to-remove-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line

Comment: To be clear: all of this output happens immediately, without actually waiting for user input? This sounds like something external to the Python process has closed its standard input. You might want to try https://superuser.com or [security.se].