# How can I get user input from a function run via concurrent.futures in Python?

Tags: python, input, concurrency, concurrent.futures

So, what I am trying to do is run a function called function, in which I try to get user input and store it in a variable called 'string', which I then return as the function ends. Then, I  submit it to a futures.ProcessPoolExecutor, and finally print its result. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from concurrent import futures

def function():
  string = input("Input: ")
  return string

executor = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

process = executor.submit(function)

print (process.result())
```

**What goes wrong:** Once I run the script, what I get is this:

```
Input: concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 232, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "./TestScript.py", line 6, in function
    string = input("Input: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./TestScript.py", line 13, in <module>
    print (process.result())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I don't ever get to give an input. I have no clue what could be going wrong. Haven't I just fully understood how concurrency and futures work? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOFError is happening because input() is encountering an EOF symbol somehere in your code before receiving any input.

When I run this in my computer I get a completely different error where concurrent.futures.process has a broken process pool.

Is this your only code? If there is more you may want to share it to get an appropriate answer.

**EDIT**

```
raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

it looks like your child starts before the parent process has finished.

Comment: This is all of my code. This is the first time I see an EOFError, so I don't really understand what in the code could cause it, or the logic behind it in general. I would appreciate it if you could briefly explain these stuff! Also, can you tell me a possible reason why you got a different error than mine? And if possible, show me the traceback or the error message in general? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: EOF is an end of file symbol. Usually a special symbol \0 that is used on the lower language level to determine when user input has stopped or if you have a print statement when that print statement should end. [this is a good example of that] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891603/how-to-remove-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)

I will edit my answer to include the errors

Comment: if you haven't [read the documentation and looked at the tutorials there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) they may help you to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Any ideas on why you got a different error than mine, and on how I can make things work? Finally, what kind of EOF character could/does my script contain that makes the program crash?

Comment: NOTE: I have just ran the script again, and I got the same error as yours, but without changing anything from my script. What could have caused that?

Comment: I am unsure. try changing the import statement to

`from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor`

Also is there a space in your print statement at the bottom in your actual code?

Comment: Good news! I fixed the issue by using ThreadPoolExecutor instead of ProcessPoolExecutor, as I saw this: 'ThreadPoolExecutor uses a pool of worker threads within a single process to execute tasks concurrently, making it suitable for I/O-bound tasks. ProcessPoolExecutor, on the other hand, uses a pool of worker processes, each running in its own separate process, which makes it ideal for CPU-bound tasks.'

Comment: fantastic. Sorry I wasn't more help.

Comment: Well, you explained to me some new stuff, and made me question things I wouldn't. More importantly: you tried to help, something that is less convenient than just scrolling down the list of questions. I really appreciated your help; no need to feel sorry! Have a good day!